# Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (3): `c' used. with tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I have a table

```
\begin{table}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c *{6}{Y}}
\toprule
 Compare with game & \multicolumn{2}{3}{95\% confidence interval} & p-value\\
\midrule
P1 & 0.45 & 0.28 & 9e-06 \\
P2 & -0.94 & -0.43 & 9e-05 \\
P3 & 0.36 & 0.74 & 7e-05 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\captionsetup{width=.9\linewidth}
\caption{My caption}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}%
```

and the error is reported at the line `\end{tabularx}`. I searched through the site but it seems to me that no one have exact same problem with me.

**Update:**

Here is my 'Y' definition:

```
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

Comment: It seems you have not defined the "Y" column; can you please give us the definition?

Comment: Your `\multicolumn` call is wrong...

Comment: you have specified `{3}`  as the alignment to `\multicolumn` but please always post a complete document that shows the error not disconnected fragments.

Answer (score 1):

As it states in the error message in the title, the illegal specification is `3` the error is

```
 \multicolumn{2}{3}{95\% confidence interval}
```

which should be

```
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% confidence interval}
```

The error is reported at the `\end{tabularx}` as the entire `tabularx` environment is saved (to allow multiple trial width settings) before it is evaluated, so before the error is seen.